# ant script taskdef and classname not found

Tags: ant, cruisecontrol

i am not very familar with taskdef and classname... i am having trouble running an ant script from another ant script:

```
2011-05-25 15:50:26,040 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - BUILD FAILED
2011-05-25 15:50:26,040 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - C:\Work\6.70_Extensions\NightlyBuild\nightly_build.xml:31: The following error occurred while executing this line:
2011-05-25 15:50:26,040 [Thread-23] WARN  ScriptRunner     - C:\Work\6.70_Extensions\NightlyBuild\Master Build.xml:6: taskdef class com.ANT_Tasks.CFileEdit cannot be found
```

where line 6 is:

```
<taskdef mame="CFileEdit" classname="com.ANT_Tasks.CFileEdit" />
```

my root directory is C:\Work\6.70_Extensions\NightlyBuild and i have a folder C:\Work\6.70_Extensions\NightlyBuild\com\ANT_Tasks and i have a CFileEdit.java in that folder. Anybody knows what is wrong?

**Edit:**

I do not wish to change the structure of my ANT script, therefore what is the next step here?

1. i Complied my CFileEdit.java file into CFileEdit.class
2. I converted CFileEdit.class into CFileEdit.jar
3. i put this CFileEdit.jar into C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\lib where this is my ant directory?

please tell me if i am doing it right or wrong, i am having issues with this currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must compile the `.java` into a `.class` and use the class for `classpath` for the `taskdef`

1. Compile CFileEdit.java
2. Define taskdef as follows -

> ```
> <taskdef name="CFileEdit" classname="com.ANT_Tasks.CFileEdit"> 
>     <classpath>
>         <!-- refer to the compiled class here along with others as necessary to execute the task -->
>       </classpath>
> </taskdef>
> ```

Comment: under classpath, is it to provide the path of cfileedit after compiling?

Comment: is it possible to compile, and not edit the ant script? i do not wish to make any changes to my ant script..

Comment: `is it to provide the path of cfileedit after compiling?` Yes. Use a `<pathelement path="path-to-package-root-of-CFileEdit"/>` inside `<classpath>` tag. This path should contain com/ANT_Tasks/CFileEdit.class, ie it gets resolved from package root. Other Question: `Is it possible to compile, and not edit the ant script?` Yes if you are willing to copy the class in `ANT_HOME/lib` directory after putting it in a `.jar`

Comment: hi with regards to part 2 of your answer, i changed my .class into jar. then i will just put this .jar file into `ANT_HOME/lib`? what about the name of the `jar` file? `com.ANT_Tasks.CFileEdit.jar`?

Comment: Names of jar files are not significant as long as they are on classpath. So it should work.